# Talking between Arduino and Java

Tags: java, arduino

I have to realize a communication between Arduino Leonardo and a demon which runs on a pc.

The demon has to tell Arduino informations about the operative system of the machine to which it is linked,the dimension of the screen and other things about its state.

As it has to work both on Windows and on MAC Os, I thought to write the demon in Java, but I've seen that the library `RXTX` for communication is hardware dependent, so it can create problems if I use a different machine.

In your opinion shall I use `Processing`, or there is another way to achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Processing which has a nice [serial library](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial) that works on Windows/OSX/Linux, however it has a dependency on Processing's main class: PApplet (which as name hints, is an Applet subclass).

The library, as Processing is opensource, so you can adjust the RXTX wrapper it provides to work without PApplet (as a Daemon/service/etc.) if you need too. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215945/jssc-not-sending-data-to-arduino/26268106#26268106) to see what I mean.